# No option for providing JSON request body string via Swagger UI for Open API Enabled Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to build an Open API enabled HTTP trigger Azure Function. Everything goes good if I try to hit from postman because I can provide the body of request. But in swagger its asking for name parameter. No option for specifying the real request body..
[image]

How can I accomplish that.

here is my function configuration

```
[FunctionName("ObjectRead")]
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "name" })]
[OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
[OpenApiParameter(name: "name", In = ParameterLocation.Header, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **Name** parameter")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"ObjectRead function triggered at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")}.");

    var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileDetails>(requestBody);
    var responseMessage = await _objectReadService.ReadAsync(data.FileName, data.FilePath).ConfigureAwait(false);

    _logger.LogInformation($"ObjectRead function completed at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")}.");
    return responseMessage.Length != 0 ? new FileStreamResult(responseMessage, "application/octet-stream") : new NotFoundObjectResult("Unable to retrieve the file or File not found.");
}
```

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 1):

I have got an answer for my question which I would like to share to others who faces the same challenge

By just specifying

```
[OpenApiRequestBody("application/json", typeof(FileDetails))]
```

as a function header Now the request body as JSON also shows.

[image]

Here Filedetails is my model class for request